# Postgresql 9.6 with multi-tenancy - INHERIT says child table has column with different data type but it doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I've been working with a legacy rails app that has had the same "inherit" migration that has run plenty of times in the past but suddenly is complaining that one of the child tables has a column of different type than the parent table in the public schema, but when I inspect things in the database, that doesn't appear to be true. See code examples below

**Error**

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch("child_schema")

# local variable assigned in a looping array of table names...
table = "categories"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE #{table} INHERIT public.#{table}")

-- ERROR:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  child table "categories" has different type for column "name"
: ALTER TABLE categories INHERIT public.categories

from /var/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
```

**Inspection**

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select column_name,data_type from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'child_schema' AND table_name = 'categories';").to_a

 => [{"column_name"=>"id", "data_type"=>"integer"}, {"column_name"=>"name", "data_type"=>"character varying"}] 


> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select column_name,data_type from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'categories';").to_a

=> [{"column_name"=>"id", "data_type"=>"integer"}, {"column_name"=>"name", "data_type"=>"character varying"}]
```

I'm really at a loss here for what to do, I have tried searching google and SO, looking over postgresql INHERIT docs, rooting around for rails / apartment issues, and cannot find any information.

**Update**

It looks like if I do this:

```
> Category.connection.columns('public.categories')
> Category.connection.columns('child_schema.categories')
```

I get a difference in column types now:

```
# Public parent table:
=> [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn: #...
@name="name", #...
@sql_type="character varying(255)" #...

# child_schema child table:
=> [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn: #...
@name="name", #...
@sql_type="character varying" #...
```

Alright, so... anyone have a clue how I might find out why the child schema table got a slightly different type?

I can't find that there is any migration to adjust the column type / length, and the tenant creation code just runs apartment's tenant create method with the tenant name.

Comment: You should look at the db itself.  I'm guessing that they are both character varying, but have different lengths.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy -  in my latest update I was able to find out that your guess is spot on, but I don't know how that could have happened. There is no migration file that calls for changing the length on the field and db/schema.rb just shows 

 create_table "categories" .. t.string "name"

and nothing more

Answer (score 0):

This one was my fault and Apartment schema issues were a bit of red herring as a result: https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/626#issuecomment-573206304